# What does the Phantom's ring mean?

Tags: league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

Watching "The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen" , at the start when the tank busts through the banks walls we first see the Phantom.

When he gets out the camera is focused on the Phantom's ring,

[image]

To me it looks like it says ["Women"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3) in Japanese,

[image]

Was there anything that stated what the ring was supposed to be or mean?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a [Masonry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry) symbol, not Japanese writing. Masons have been attributed virtually any and all kinds of conspiracies around the world, so if that "Phantom" is a negative character, the reasoning is pretty straight.

**P.S**: I didn't watch the movie, nor did I have the patience to read the graphic novel in its entirety; feel free to correct me.

[image]

Comment: got a source for that?

Comment: BTW, did you answer the question before I posted? that was fast!

Comment: @KyloRen  -   click on your own image and enlarge it, you can see it's the same symbol. (although without the "G" at the centre, but nonetheless)

Comment: It looks the same to me, just wondering if you had a source to state that that was the actual meaning of the ring in the movie. I doubt it means he is a Japanese playboy BTW

Comment: Anyway, I will upvote this answer.

Comment: @KyloRen This link shows the Masonic compass & square without the G inside https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRRVzKIJl__-oXnzJ-JpJPF695hBXZ3CRcSK-HvHdXqGyLtZg6uyQ

Comment: The Freemasons are frequently associated with [Shadow Government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_government_(conspiracy)) quackery; they're portrayed as an enigmatic group that manipulates world events from behind the scenes, with only a few knowing the truth. This is also a fairly accurate description of Moriarty in the *Holmes* canon, and of the Phantom/Moriarty/M in *League of Extraordinary Gentlemen*. Also [Doyle was one](http://www.grandlodgescotland.com/masonic-subjects/famous-freemasons)

Comment: @JasonBaker  -  exactly.